# Error in django using Apache & mod_wsgi

Tags: django, apache, mod-wsgi

Hey, I've been doing some changes to my django develpment env, as some of you suggested.
So far I've managed to configure and run it successfully with postgres.

Now I'm trying to run the app using apache2 and mod_wsgi, but I ran into this little problem after I followed the guidelines from the django docs.

When I access localhost/myapp/tasks this error raises:

```
    Request Method:   GET
Request URL:  http://localhost/myapp/tasks/
Exception Type:  TemplateSyntaxError
Exception Value:  

Caught an exception while rendering: argument 1 must be a string or unicode object

Original Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/django/template/debug.py", line 71, in render_node
    result = node.render(context)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/django/template/defaulttags.py", line 126, in render
    len_values = len(values)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 81, in __len__
    self._result_cache = list(self.iterator())
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 238, in iterator
    for row in self.query.results_iter():
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/django/db/models/sql/query.py", line 287, in results_iter
    for rows in self.execute_sql(MULTI):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/django/db/models/sql/query.py", line 2369, in execute_sql
    cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/django/db/backends/util.py", line 19, in execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
TypeError: argument 1 must be a string or unicode object
... ... ...
```

And then it highlights a {% for t in tasks %} template tag, like the source of the problem is there, but it worked fine on the built-in server.

The view associated with that page is *really* simple, just fetch all Task objects. And the template just displays them on a table.

Also, *some* pages get rendered ok.
Don't want to fill this Question with code, so if you need some more info I'd be glad to provide it. Thanks

**EDIT**

So, here is my view:

```
@login_required
def tasks(request, msg=''):
    tasks = Task.objects.all()
    message = msg
    return custom_render('user/tasks.html',
                         {'tasks': tasks, 'message':message},
                         request)
```

And here is my template:

```
{% block main_content %}

{% if message %}
    <p id="message" class="info">
        {{message}}
    </p>
{% endif %}

<a href="{% url GProject.myapp.views.new_task %}">Nueva Tarea</a>

    <table  id="tasks-table" >
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th colspan="4" >{{tasks|length}} tareas pendientes</th>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <th>#</th>
                <th>Proyecto</th>
                <th>Título</th>
                <th>Estado</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            {% for t in tasks %}
                <tr id="row-{{t.id}}" class="{% cycle 'row-0' 'row-1' %} priority-{{ t.priority }}">
                    <td width="25">
                       <a href="{% url GProject.myapp.views.view_task t.id %}">{{t.id}}</a>
                   </td>
                   <td>
                       <a href="{% url GProject.myapp.views.view_task t.id %}">{{t.project}}</a>
                   </td>
                   <td width="400">
                       <a href="{% url GProject.myapp.views.view_task t.id %}">
                           {{t.title}}
                       </a>
                   </td>
                   <td>{{t.get_status_display}}</td>
                </tr>
            {% empty %}
                <tr><td>No tasks</td></tr>
            {% endfor %}

        </tbody>
    </table>
{% endblock main_content %}
```

Also, now I'm getting *this* error:

```
TypeError at /admin/tareas/

argument 1 must be a string or unicode object

Request Method:  GET
Request URL:  http://localhost/gpro/admin/tareas/
Exception Type:  TypeError
Exception Value:  

argument 1 must be a string or unicode object

Exception Location:  /usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/django/db/backends/postgresql_psycopg2/base.py in _cursor, line 105
Python Executable:  /usr/bin/python
Python Version:  2.5.4
```

**EDIT**

Tasks model looks like this:

```
class Task(models.Model):

    project = models.ForeignKey(Project)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=128)
    description = models.TextField(max_length=1500)
    effort = models.IntegerField(null=True, blank=True)
    priority = models.IntegerField(max_length=1, null=True, blank=True, choices=PRIORITY_VALUES)
    severity = models.IntegerField(max_length=1, null=True, blank=True, choices=SEVERITY_VALUES)
    asignee = models.ForeignKey(User, blank=True, null=True, related_name='asignee')
    milestone = models.ForeignKey(Milestone, blank=True, null=True)
    created_by = models.ForeignKey(User, blank=True, null=True, related_name='created_by')
    status = models.IntegerField(max_length=1, choices=STATUS_VALUES, default=1)
    resolution_comment = models.CharField(max_length=1500, null=True, blank=True) #comentario al resolver la task
    due_date = models.DateField(blank=True, null=True)
    created_on = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add = True)

    #print    
    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.title
```

custom_render:

```
def custom_render(template_name, data_dict, request):
    return render_to_response(template_name,
                              data_dict,
                              context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

Comment: Could you modify the django source and print repr of sql and params?
When the code is ran under devserver and apache

Comment: Piotr, I'm really not sure how to do that..

Comment: Django doesn't always point out the correct line in the template. Don't trust it too much.

Comment: put DEBUG_PROPAGATE_EXCEPTIONS=True into your settings.py file and reload the page, you should see original exception. also post view and template code.

Comment: The error is not related to apache nor mod_wsgi, it's a TemplateSyntaxError.

Are you using custom templatetags?
Could you provide the template?

Comment: Sorry I hadn' time to provide more data. I will try to provide it today.
@DZPM: The thing is that with the built-in server ir works ok, it's weird. I'll publish the views and template today. Thanks.

Comment: I have no idea, but:
- does {{t.get_status_display}} need an argument?
- in your views.py, "tasks" is a method but also a variable. Maybe it's getting confused? I would change the variable name to "task_list".
- Try "divide and conquer". Keep deleting stuff from your template, until it renders ok, so you find where the error is...

Comment: What does your Task class look like?  Can you provide the code for at least the methods you're calling in the template?

Comment: What is your `custom_render` doing?

Comment: Seems the problem is something in config or prior to rendering. No matter what do I put in the template or view, same error.

Comment: The traceback looks like it's encountering an error while resolving the `{{tasks|length}}` in the template. I suggest that you expand the QuerySet before passing it to the renderer, see if you get a more informative error: `tasks = list(Task.objects.all())`

Answer (score 0):

Just given that you do not encounter the problem running manage.py runserver, and you do encounter the problem using mod_wsgi, i'd look at database permissions.

First, are you running mod_wsgi as the same user as you are running python manage.py runserver? If not you need to grant the mod_wsgi user permissions. As an example, try something like this, where apache is the name of the user running mod_wsgi:

```
sudo su - postgres
createuser -S -D -R apache
psql
< should now be in the psql shell >
grant all on database < your database name > to apache;
```

Comment: Also think it might be DB related, but this didn't do the trick.